# SQL exception : non supported token at position 3 JAVA

Tags: java, sql, database, spring-boot

I'm getting java.sql.sqlEception : non supported token SQL92 token ant position 3 exception for a simple select query.

please find the query below.

```
SELECT contract from contract_table
```

sql.properties

```
FETCH.CONTRACT=SELECT contract from contract_table
```

contractDAOImpl

```
public class ContractDAOImpl implements ContractDAO{
    
    @Value("${FETCH.CONTRACT}")
    private String fetchContract;
    
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbc;
    
    public JdbcTemplate getjdbc(){
        return jdbc; 
    }
    
    public void setjdbc(JdbcTemplate jdbc){
        this.jdbc=jdbc; 
    }
    
    public List<ContractEntity> getValue(){
        Connection conn=null
        PreparedStatement stmt=null;
        Resultset res=null;
    
        conn=jdbc.getConnection();
        stmt=conn.PreparedStatement(fetchContract);
        res=stmt.executeQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: We're missing some information here, because the SQL statement you showed above should be valid, assuming that this table and column really exist.  Maybe include the full relevant Java code in your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sql was working fine with the code. and when i tried with a new workspace also its working. also the sql is getting data in sql developer. but all of a sudden in console. i'm getting sql exception

Comment: Please add your Java code and the complete stack trace of the exception. The DDL for the table would also be useful.

Comment: Shouldn't **`@value("FETCH.CONTRACT")`** be **`@Value("${FETCH.CONTRACT}")`**

Comment: @pleft yes i added wrongly. i have edited it

Comment: @Nismathvi can you share what others also have asked? E.g. the complete stacktrace and the DDL of the table?